# Predefined lengths in \put

Tags: dimension-expressions

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*
{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1 mm}
    \put(52, 240){Text}
}

Some more text

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I realize I was a bit too quick when first posting, assuming that

```
\put(52 mm, 240 mm){...}
```

would be equivalent to

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1 mm}
\put(52, 240){...}
```

So the question then becomes, if I have a predefined length `\mylength` how can I get something like the following to work?

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1 mm}
\put(52, \mylength){...}
```

Comment: Are you doing `\usepackage{picture}`?

Comment: By default the first "working" version is an error, if you redefine `\put` so that works, I'd expect your second to work. Please fix your example to be a complete document that generates the error.

Comment: @egreg Adding `\usepackage{picture}` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands in the standard `picture` environment only allow numbers in their arguments, representing multiples of `\unitlength`.

One can use explicit dimensions in coordinates or displacement arguments by loading Heiko Oberdiek's package `picture`.

Thus `\usepackage{picture}` in the preamble will allow doing

```
\put(52, \mylength){...}
```

or

```
\put(52mm, \mylength){...}
```

Numbers not followed by a unit of measure will still be considered as denoting multiples of `\unitlength`.

Note that if you load `pict2e` (recommended), the loading of `picture` should follow it:

```
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
```

Note however that the explicit lengths can only go in the standard commands of `picture` mode, not in the additional ones defined by `pict2e`.